# JavaScript - Replace some letters with numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying replace some letters with numbers in JQuery, and I have initialized my object like this:

```
var myVar = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
```

I'm getting the string from an input and I want to convert these letters immediately as the user is typing in text input. I want to do it via `RegEx`.

Comment: where exactly you want to use _regex_

Comment: and what you tried?

Comment: @user2181397I want to use RegEx for converting purpose. I mean, I want to pass my object somewhere somehow, and get the converted text.

Comment: See DEMO here :  http://stackoverflow.com/a/38549137/747579

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `input` event, `String.prototype.replace()`, `RegExp()` with parameter `new RegExp(keys.join("|"), "g"` where `keys` are property names of `myVar` object

```js
var myVar = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3, "d":4};
var keys = Object.keys(myVar);
document.querySelector("input")
.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(new RegExp(keys.join("|"), "g")
                   , function(match) {
                       return myVar[match]
                   });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  :

- **Event** :  `keyup` event
- **Action** :`split` & `join` for `String` AND `map` for `Array`.

  ```
  $(INPUT_SELECTOR).keyup(function(event){
   var newVal=$(this).val().split('').map(function(ch){
      if(isFinite(ch) || !myVar[ch]){
          return ch;
     }else{
         return myVar[ch];
       }
   }).join('');
   $(this).val(newVal);

   })
  ```

## [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/vg5zjjyg/)

Comment: @jmosawy : if it is not useful , i will delete . .Plz , let me know

Comment: This code works, too! As I was looking for a solution via RegEx, I chose `guest271314` answer as my solution.